# Add extra SELECT expression result to the existing entity

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the project that allows to rate a company in many aspects. The following diagram could help you to understand the relations in my database. Of course, I have deleted from the scheme the fields, that are not important in the context of my problem.
[image: EER diagram]
Currently, in my repository class of the `Company` entity, I am searching for companies using `QueryBuilder` and returning an instance of `\Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator`.

The below code is responsible for fetching companies:

```
public function search(CompanySearchQuery $command): Paginator
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->setFirstResult($command->getOffset())
        ->setMaxResults($command->getMaxResults())
        ->orderBy('c.name', 'ASC');

    ... plus extra "where" conditions

    return new Paginator($qb, true);
}
```

I wonder how I can attach the average score to each company using `QueryBuilder` and `Paginator`.

Here is the native SQL that allows me to get data I need:

```
SELECT
  c.id,
  c.name,
  AVG(o2.score) as score
FROM
  company c
LEFT JOIN
  opinion o ON c.id = o.company_id
LEFT JOIN
  opinion_scope o2 ON o.id = o2.opinion_id
GROUP BY
  c.id
```

**My question is:** Is it possible to add `averageScore` property to the `Company` class and map it from `QueryBuilder` result?

I tried to rewrite my SQL query to use with the existing code:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
    ->select('c', 'AVG(s.score)')
    ->leftJoin('c.opinions', 'o')
    ->leftJoin('o.scopes', 's')
    ->groupBy('c.id')
    ->setFirstResult($command->getOffset())
    ->setMaxResults($command->getMaxResults())
    ->orderBy('c.name', 'ASC')
;
```

With the above code I get database exception as following:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #14 of 
SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 
'database.o1_.score' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY
clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by").
```

The SQL query that is executed for the above QueryBuilder is:

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT id_8 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      DISTINCT id_8, 
      name_9 
    FROM 
      (
        SELECT 
          c0_.updated_at AS updated_at_0, 
          c0_.description AS description_1, 
          c0_.website AS website_2, 
          c0_.email AS email_3, 
          c0_.phone AS phone_4, 
          c0_.street AS street_5, 
          c0_.postal_code AS postal_code_6, 
          c0_.city AS city_7, 
          c0_.id AS id_8, 
          c0_.name AS name_9, 
          c0_.slug AS slug_10, 
          c0_.created_at AS created_at_11, 
          AVG(o1_.score) AS sclr_12, 
          o1_.score AS score_13, 
          o1_.opinion_id AS opinion_id_14, 
          o1_.type_id AS type_id_15 
        FROM 
          company c0_ 
          LEFT JOIN opinion o2_ ON c0_.id = o2_.company_id 
          LEFT JOIN opinion_scope o1_ ON o2_.id = o1_.opinion_id 
        GROUP BY 
          c0_.id
      ) dctrn_result_inner 
    ORDER BY 
      name_9 ASC
  ) dctrn_result 
LIMIT 
  2 OFFSET 0
```

I do not understand why Doctrine adds the following fragment:

```
o1_.score AS score_13, 
o1_.opinion_id AS opinion_id_14, 
o1_.type_id AS type_id_15
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that you're trying to select every column from 'c', which is your resulting table from performing two LEFT JOINs. Instead, you need to be specifying a from clause for the company table:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('c', 'AVG(s.score)')
    ->from('company', 'c')
    ->leftJoin('c.opinions', 'o')
    ->leftJoin('o.scopes', 's')
    ->groupBy('c.id')
    ->setFirstResult($command->getOffset())
    ->setMaxResults($command->getMaxResults())
    ->orderBy('c.name', 'ASC')
;
```

This will avoid including o1.score is your returned columns, which is what that error is referencing

Comment: The SQL query I have attached works well when I execute it directly on my database, but I have a problem to rewrite it to use with Doctrine Query Builder.

Comment: I have added the SQL query generated by Doctrine.

Comment: @MichałSzczech Actually I think it's because you didnt specify a `->from` clause after the SELECT. 'c' in this case is the resulting table you get after all of the LEFT JOINs, which will include their columns in it

Comment: Edited my answer @MichałSzczech

Comment: `\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository::createQueryBuilder` method adds `from` clause using entity from current repository and an alias from first parameter of it.

Comment: If I add `->from(Company::class, 'c')` I get an error `[Semantical Error] line 0, col 113 near 'c LEFT JOIN c.opinions': Error: 'c' is already defined.`

Comment: @MichałSzczech which is why you need to remove 'c' in your querybuilder constructor. Try not specifying anything there